# Why an \hskip Command Following the Standard Linebreak Command \\ Does Not Work

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, paragraphs, parindent, vskip

Could someone explain why something like `\\ \hskip 15pt` would result in a linebreak with no indentation?

I know that one could use `\par` (seeting the indentation at 15pt), or even \vskip 0pt \hskip 15pt to accomplish the task, but at times, it would be more expedient to use something like `\\ \hskip 15pt` if only it would work.

Also, other than this, is there any difference between `\vskip 0pt` and `\\`?

Thank you.

Comment: Try  `\\ {}\hskip 15 pt`.

Comment: @Bernard It does not work on my end. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Use `\\ \hspace*{15pt}vvvv` to get a space. But you should use \par if you have  paragraph break. These commands are not only for visual effects, they have also semantic meaning.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thank you. `\\ hspace*{15pt}` seems to do the trick. Perhaps you might consider posting this as an answer with a brief explanation of why `\hspace*` works but `\hskip` does not. I have yet to try `\hspace`. I have encountered differences with these in the past. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @mlchristians see my answer are you sure you want that? Why make it look like a pargaraph to the reader but go to some lengths to stop tex treating it as a paragra[h?

Comment: @David Carlisle I'm not sure I know what you mean. Sometimes when I type quickly and want to break what I'm typing, paragraph or otherwise, on to the  next line with an indentation, it helps if I could use \\ with a horizontal spacing command.  In any case, U. Fischer points out that `\hspace*` works, which I have just verified.

Comment: \hspace* basically does \mbox{}\hspace{15pt}. So it puts something at the begin of the line before the space. But David is quite right: you are not thinking in semantics. And if you ever would want to add structure informations to your PDF for better accessibility this will bite you.

Comment: why not simply hit `<return>` twice That ends the paragraph. `\\ \hspace*{15pt}` is much more to type and it instructs tex to _not_ end the paragraph: all its internal structures (and any accessibility tagging) will carefuly construct this as a single paragraph with a short line in the middle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

white space (glue) is dropped after a linebreak in a paragraph, so that inter-word spaces are dropped if a line break is inserted. To TeX `\\ \hskip 15pt` is the same.

Note that adding a `\par` or (better) a blank line is completely different, `\par` ends the paragraph, whereas `\\`  just adds a linebreak possibility within a paragraph and does not end the paragraph or trigger the linebreaking algorithm.

Similarly `\vskip0pt` (which is a TeX primitive which should not be used in a latex document) is very different from `\\` .  `\vskip` ads a vertical skip so should be used in vertical mode. If you use it within a paragraph then as a recovery TeX will insert `\par` to end the current paragraph then re-execute the `\vskip`. Conversely `\\`  may only be used in horizontal mode, marking a line break point, it gives an error if used in vertical mode.

as noted in comments you *could* to

```
aaa \\\hspace*{15pt} bbb
```

but there are essentially no use cases for this. To the reader this will look like the start of a paragraph but it is not, it is just a single paragraph with a 15pt space at the start of one line, so for example all paragraph level controls such as widow penalties or `\finalhyphendemerits` and `\parfillskip` will not apply to the separate "paragraphs" but just to the single paragraph with the forced line break.

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive explanation. I appreciate it.